# distinct doesn't work for some select fields

Tags: sql

I have below query to select from multiple tables.

```
select distinct s.playerId PlayerID, h.name TeamName, 
    m.firstname FirstName, m.lastname LastName, h.year Year
from scoringnew s 
join
(select max(s.pts) pts,s.tmid from  scoringnew s group by s.tmid) t
on s.tmid = t.tmid and s.pts = t.pts
join master m on (m.playerId = s.playerId)
join ice_hockey_teams_new h on (h.tmid = s.tmid);
```

the result is showing distinct `PlayerID` correctly. But if I add more columns on select it will show duplicate `PlayerID` like below:

```
select distinct s.playerId PlayerID, h.name TeamName, 
    m.firstname FirstName, m.lastname LastName, h.year Year, s.pts Points
from scoringnew s 
join
(select max(s.pts) pts,s.tmid from  scoringnew s group by s.tmid) t
on s.tmid = t.tmid and s.pts = t.pts
join master m on (m.playerId = s.playerId)
join ice_hockey_teams_new h on (h.tmid = s.tmid);
```

the only different between the above queries is that the second query has one more select field `s.pts Points` which gives duplicate `PlayerID` in result set.
I wonder why `distinct` doesn't work for all cases. Is there anything I misunderstand about it?

The duplicate rows shown as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't you mean to select t.pts?

```
select distinct s.playerId PlayerID, h.name TeamName, 
m.firstname FirstName, m.lastname LastName,     h.year Year, t.pts Points
from scoringnew s 
join
(select max(s.pts) pts,s.tmid from  scoringnew s group by s.tmid) t
on s.tmid = t.tmid
join master m on (m.playerId = s.playerId)
join ice_hockey_teams_new h on (h.tmid = s.tmid);
```

Comment: pts exists in both t and s table.

Comment: Correct, but I assume that s contains multiple records given that you are selecting the max in t.

Comment: yes, s does contain multiple records. but I have placed distinct why it doesn't work?

Comment: Please post the output that you're receiving. I'm guessing that the points in s have many DIFFERENT values hence the reason for multiple records.

Comment: I have updated the post to include output data set. You are right that the points in table s has many different values. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can't expect 1 record when you're joining on a table that has multiple records based on your join. Do you want the sum of the points?

Comment: I don't want the sum of the points. I want to the maximum point.

Comment: @ZhaoYi select t.pts then.. post the output of that

Comment: I tried to select p.pts but still not work. I was wrong about the issue. Actually, I found that one of the reason is that year has a different value. I am trying to find a way to give distinct year from `ice_hockey_teams_new` table.

Comment: I recommend that you post the structures of these tables and also edit the question to include the desired output. I'll help you resolve this afterwards.